# How Do I pass parameters with a render call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, render

This is a simple question. If a form isn't filled out correctly, I call `render 'new'` in my create action so the person can fill out the form correctly. Unfortunately, this causes the loss of the parameters that were in the URL. How do I pass them along with the render call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action method should pick up the parameters and assign it to an instance variable. The model in this example is called note.

```
def create
    @note = Note.new(params[:note])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save
        format.html { redirect_to @note, notice: 'Note was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

The instance variable is then visible within your view:

```
<%= form_for(@note) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the parameters are passed as hidden fields in the form itself so that you can get from them in the create action.

Answer (score 0):

The render call should be using variables with "@" on them (aka, instance variables). Make sure #create has the same instance variables as #new.

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is you define them has hidden fields and declare the hidden field as attr_accessor in the model, but if you insists to pass get parameters even when is supposed to use only post parameters you can write all your params in your form action like:

form_for @event, :url => events_path+'?getvar=1' do |f|